# How to create JSON array in Javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am creating a cordova ionic app. I want to create an object like below JSON. I want to send a JSON request like below which I need to create Dynamically. **BELOW IS JUST AN EXAMPLE. I WANT TO CREATE IT IN JS.**

```
{
    user_id: "72",
    data: {
        [{
            "id": "2",
            "name": "1",
            "occupation": "30",
            "type": [{
                "shape_id": "9",
                "sizey": "6",
                "sizex": "4",
                "price": "6"
            }, {
                "shape_id": "8",
                "sizey": "6",
                "sizex": "6",
                "price": "4.68"
            }, {
                "shape_id": "4",
                "sizey": "4",
                "sizex": "4",
                "price": "2.08"
            }],
        }]
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you're asking? JSON is a subset of JavaScript. So if you want to create that in JavaScript source code, you literally just write what you have, presumably with a `var data = ` in front of it and a `;` at the end. (Or pass it into a function, etc.)

Comment: Can you be specific about which key-value pair you are looking to add?

Comment: Also note that what you appear to have is an object, which is an entirely separate entity from JSON.

Comment: It seems there is an issue with "data" property. "{[{" will cause error. You can not use array without name in object

Comment: _I have values_.....but then there is no relative way to assign a key to the value. So, here I don't get it what to answer as question is not clear.

Answer (score 0):

Just use what you provided and put it inside a variable

You can remove the quotes from number depending on your need. Without the quote it will be a number instead of a string

```
user_id : "72"
```

can be replace by

```
user_id : 72
```

```js
var data = {
  user_id: "72",
  data: [{
    "id": "2",
    "name": "1",
    "occupation": "30",
    "type": [{
      "shape_id": "9",
      "sizey": "6",
      "sizex": "4",
      "price": "6"
    }, {
      "shape_id": "8",
      "sizey": "6",
      "sizex": "6",
      "price": "4.68"
    }, {
      "shape_id": "4",
      "sizey": "4",
      "sizex": "4",
      "price": "2.08"
    }],
  }]
}


console.log(data);
```

Comment: The first statement you made, removing quotes around the number isn't necessarily true. The difference between the `"72"` and `72` is the first one is a string, the second one is a number/integer. If he needs it to be a string, turning it into a number could break something or vice versa.

Comment: Actually I dont want to access the data... i just want to create a JSON request like this to send it to server using ajax call...

Comment: @Anjana-Systematix Then simply use the `data` variable

Comment: @Anjana-Systematix if you're wanting to send the data over, you're going to need your server setup to be able to accept that kind of request, then you'll just post through the variable data. This will post the whole object through, including userId, and the data array with all that info in it.

Comment: How can I create that data array? @JoshuaTerrill I don't know how to create that... I just showed a sample above what kind of request i need...

Comment: @Anjana-Systematix What do you want ? The object **IS CREATED**. You can access is as shown inside `console.log(data)`

Comment: `var data = [{ name: "value", name2: "value2" }]`

Comment: @Weedoze it was just a sample... i want to create it dynamically

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
jsonObj = [];

item = {}
item ["key"] = "value";
item ["key2"] = jsonObj2;
jsonObj.push(item);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a javascript obj like:

```
var obj={id: 2, name: "name"};
```

And then use `JSON.stringify(obj)` for getting your json string.